# Type 'B' does not have a constructor with parameters of types?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a class `A`. While creating class A, I must run class `B` (and pass an instance of `A` as a parameter) but when running, I get an error that I cannot initialize the object? What is the cause and how to solve it?

Specific example:

```
public class A: UserControl
{
    private A ()
    {
      InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent ()
    {
        B _B1 = new B (this); // error: Type 'B' does not have a constructor with parameters of types
    }
}

public class B
{
    private class A _classA;
    public B (class A a1)
    {
        _classA = a1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor of `B` should be declared as `public B (A a1)`. Is the extra word "class" a typo or a genuine mistake?

Comment: Thank! typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Define your Class B like this. You dont define the argument with `class`.

```
public class B
{
    private A _classA;
    public B(A a1)
    {
        _classA = a1;
    }
}
```

Even then, once you initialize your Class B like this, you will need another method or property to retrieve the value of `_classA`. (`public A ClassA => _classA;` perhaps.)

Comment: Thank! I think there may be an error using class A (this) to get parameters passed to class B (B _B = new A (this)). while class A has not been initialized yet in method InitializeComponent () of class A, Do not know right?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `public B (A a1) { _classA = a1; }`

Comment: Thank! while class A has not been initialized yet, can we take class A (this) as a passing parameter for class B?

Comment: If not initialised then why are you passing it? Do you want to initialise A in B constructor?

Comment: The purpose is to get the fields, methods of class A for class B to use,Is there any solution to the above problem?

Comment: You can create object of B like this new B(new A()); and call the methods like this _classA.SomeMathodofClassA();